Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL open server 6.0 phpmyadmin
Запускаю phpMyAdmin через open server 6.0. Следую данной инструкции: https://delphinpro.ru/a/6
Ввожу пользователя root и не ввожу пароль в соответствии с настройками.
Получаю ошибки:


Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL


mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for MySQL-8.0 failed: ���� ���� ����������.


mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for MySQL-8.0 failed: ���� ���� ����������.

Замена имени пользователя и пароля на root, mysql и admin не помогает.

Вопрос решился.
При настройке в файле config.inc.php указал $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MySQL-8.2';
Ранее указывал MySQL-8.0

Ребята предыдущий ответ не совсем верный. Дело в том что на моем компьютере еще установлен MySQL80 и видимо он работает на том же порту что и Open Server Panel.
То есть они мешают друг другу. Ответ такой -- запускаем Диспетчер задач, во вкладке Подробности завершаем задачу всего что связано с mysql. Тогда ошибок не возникает и phpmyadmin запускается корректно.
В настройках OpenServer 6 надо всего лишь включить соответствующий модуль MySQL.

Этот ответ вы принимаете за верный? Пожалуйста, удалите тогда свой предыдущий ответ во избежания запутывания. Если этот ответ помог вам — примите его (нажмите зелёную галочку слева). Также Дух сообщества (бот) предложил дополнить ваш ответ. Его дополнение является верным? "В настройках OpenServer 6 надо всего лишь включить соответствующий модуль MySQL." — вы использовали данное? Если нет, то эту строку нужно стереть

У вас сейчас 2 ответа, один из которых нужно удалить

У меня ошибка была такая:
Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL
mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for MySQL-8.0 failed:
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for MySQL-8.0 failed:

То есть я думаю такая же, как в заданном вопросе. Я долго ничего не мог сделать. Но потом в Sublume Text открыл следующие файлы:

D:\OSPanel\home\phpmyadmin.osp\project.ini

Его содержимое:
[phpmyadmin]
php_engine  = php-8.1
public_dir  = {base_dir}/public


D:\OSPanel\home\phpmyadmin\public\config.inc.php

В его содержимое я добавил следующее:
/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MySQL-8.0';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/**
 * Second server
 */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MySQL-5.7';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;


При запуске OSPanel изменяет файл C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts и добавляет следующее:

127.127.126.32 php-8.1
127.127.126.32 php-8.1.local
127.127.126.32 php-example
<i>127.127.126.25 mysql-5.7
127.127.126.25 mysql-5.7.local</i>
<i>127.127.126.32 mysql-8.0
127.127.126.32 mysql-8.0.local</i>
127.127.126.32 www.php-example
127.127.126.32 phpmyadmin
127.127.126.32 www.phpmyadmin
127.127.127.127 ospanel
127.127.127.127 ospanel.local


И файле D:\OSPanel\config\MySQL-8.0\default\settings.ini я изменил ip. Изменил его на ip = 127.127.126.32, как у mysql-8.0 в файле hosts

И в файле D:\OSPanel\config\MySQL-5.7\default\settings.ini ip = 127.127.126.25, как у mysql-5.7 в файле hosts


И у меня всё заработало

Я привожу цитату человека  который задаёт  вопрос "Запускаю phpmyadmin через open server 6.0. Следую данной инструкции https://delphinpro.ru/a/6 Ввожу пользователь root и не ввожу пароль в соответствии с настройками" у него есть ссылка на внешний ресурс и он написал что использует имя пользователя root и пустой пароль и он не цитирует никакую информацию из этого источника и ему ничего никто не пишет про это. и я отредактировал ответ и ссылки не указывал а показал какая ошибка возникла у меня и что я сделал какие правки в каких файлах.
